# can't install R package from zip file

Tags: r, rstudio

I installed `SDSFoundations package` from `zip file` and `error` occurred as shown in the image. I try to change `type = "source" or "both"` but it can't fix this problem.

`OS: Windows 10`.

Any suggestion?

Error:

[image]

Comment: Please post errors as formatted text instead of screenshots. This makes it more search enginge friendly and prevents that the image could become unavailable

Comment: I agree with @Freggar. plus, it seems to be a package offered by a private compagnie (EDX) so we can't reproduce it. Please contact them.